# On the proper way to express statements (Basic)

Tags: logic, notation, self-learning

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $f$ be a real $k$-periodic sequence, i.e., $f(n)=f(n+rk)$ for every natural numbers $r$ and $n$. Denote by $A$ the set o multiples of the number $k$. To describe this periodic property, what are the differences between the notations:

1. $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\forall s\in A:f(n)=f(n+s)$;
2. $\forall  s\in A :f(s)=f(s+n)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$;
3. $\forall  s\in A :f(s)=f(s+n)$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$;
4. For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $s\in A$, $f(n)=f(n+s)$.

All four statements can be used to express the same idea? These are things that I use without attention, but I know that there might be logical issues there.

Can someone give me clarifications about it?

Comment: $1.$ is equivalent to $4.$ because first we use "for all n" , and for each such $n$ we use "for all s". $2.$ is the same because we assume that $n$ is an arbitary natural number. And finally $3.$ is the same because we state that the equation (for every fixed s) holds for every natural number n. My personal favourite way to express it is $4.$

Comment: I would prefer saying $f(n)=f(n+k)$ for all $n$.  This is easier to understand, and less error-prone.  (In your (2) and (3) do you mean to have $f(s)$ on the left-hand sides of the equations?)

Comment: Thank you for the comments

Comment: @kimchilover yes

Comment: Something is fishy with (2) and (3).  One has $k\in A$ so $f(k)=f(k+n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, which is _not_ implied by (1) and (4).

Comment: @kimchilover Do you mean that I could obtain the equivalence by changing the order of $n$ and $s$ in (1) and (4)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that to require $f(n)=f(n+s)$ for all  $n\in\Bbb N$ and $s\in A$ is not the same as requiring $f(s)=f(n+s)$ for the same $n,s$.

Statements (1) and (4) are equivalent, statements (2) and (3) are equivalent, but (1) and (2) are not.  Let $f(n)=(3+(-1)^n)/2$, which has period $2$.  It clearly obeys (1).  But according to statement (2), $f(2)=f(2+n)$ for all $n$, which is clearly not the case for $n=1$ since $f(2)=2$ but $f(3)=f(2+1)=1\ne f(2)$.

You probably meant to write $f(n)=f(n+s)$ in formulas (2) and (3), but the intricacies of your notation mixed you up.